# Show that $B$ it is unbounded

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ a Banach space of infinity dimension. Show that any open set $B$, with $B \neq \emptyset$, is unbounded in the weak topology.

Comment: that this information will help me? how?

Comment: would be because of the weak convergence?

Comment: It's not related to weak _convergence_, but rather to weak _topology_ and its definition.

Comment: I do not understand ... because for me the weak topology is the smallest class that contains the continuous functions with respect to weak convergence.

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva: That makes no sense. A topology is not a class of functions.

Answer (score 9):

Recall that if $X$ is a normed space, we can define continuous linear functionals (with respect to the given norm) and denote $X^*$ this collection. The weak topology is the most economic topology making continuous each elements of $X^*$.

If $O$ is an open subset containing $0$, then $0$ admits a basic neighborhood $V$contained in $O$, that is, an element of the form 
$$V=\bigcap_{j=1}^N\{x,|f_j(x)|<r\},$$
where $f_j\in X^*$ and $r$ is positive.

Thus $V$ contains $\bigcap_{j=1}^N\ker f_j$, and so does $O$. 
Since $X$ is infinite dimensional we can find $x_0\neq 0$ such that $f_j(x_0)=0$ for all $j\in \{1,\dots,N\}$. Hence $O\supset \{\lambda x_0,\lambda\in\Bbb R\}$.

Comment: not understand why the fact that the dimension is infinite follows that there is $ x_0 $... thanks

Comment: Define $T\colon X\to \Bbb R^N$ by $T(x)=(f_1(x),\dots,f_N(x))$. If there were no $x$ as in the answer, then $T$ would be injective and $X$ would be finite dimensional.

Comment: The dimension of the kernel of a non-zero functional is 1 less than the dimension of the space it's defined on. So $\dim \ker(f_1)$ is also infinite, and so $f_2$ restricted to that also takes (at most) one from the dimension etc. So the intersection of finitely many kernels of functionals in an infinite dimensional space is still infinite-dimensional.